# How do you filter a key inside an object wrapped in an array?

Tags: angular

here I have an array like below,
then I will send this data to the API as shown below

```
{
assignStudents: [
    {
       isAssigned: true,
       binusID: "1640000616", 
       fullname: "ACHMAD FARID WADJDI", 
       acadOrg: "DRM", 
       acadPlan: "Strategy & Growth"
    },
    {
       isAssigned: true,
       binusID: "0660003053",
       fullname: "AFAN GALIH SALMAN",
       acadOrg: "DCS", 
       acadPlan: "Computer Science"
    },
    {
       isAssigned: false,
       binusID: "BN001047135",
       fullname: "AGUNG YUNANTO",
       acadOrg: "DRM",
       acadPlan: "Strategy & Growth
    },
 ],
 academicTermID: ""
}
```

[parameters in the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaTWJ.png)

I have a problem when posting data, so I must first choose the data to be posted, namely binusID and acadOrg.

My question is how to filter the keys inside an object wrapped in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to keep only the object keys you need before you post the data. Working snippet below.

```js
var data = {
  assignStudents: [
    {
       isAssigned: true,
       binusID: "1640000616", 
       fullname: "ACHMAD FARID WADJDI", 
       acadOrg: "DRM", 
       acadPlan: "Strategy & Growth"
    },
    {
       isAssigned: true,
       binusID: "0660003053",
       fullname: "AFAN GALIH SALMAN",
       acadOrg: "DCS", 
       acadPlan: "Computer Science"
    },
    {
       isAssigned: false,
       binusID: "BN001047135",
       fullname: "AGUNG YUNANTO",
       acadOrg: "DRM",
       acadPlan: "Strategy & Growth"
    },
  ],
  academicTermID: ""
};

data.assignStudents = data.assignStudents.map(e => {
    return {binusianID: e.binusID, acadOrg: e.acadOrg};
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: wow that's very good, thank you very much guys. Now I can continue my projects